# Access Mail Merge to different documents based on specific criteria

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to take a code that I have for merging to a document and set up an if...then that will merge to a different document based on a specific text in a field in a table.

My code that works.

```
Sub SendConfirmation_Click(CourseNumber As Index)
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "ConfirmationMailMerge"

        Dim LevelIConf As String
        Dim OpenWord As Object

        'Path to word document
        LevelIConf = "G:\POSTPROFESSIONAL\NAIOMT\Classes\PTH536 Level I\LevelIConf.doc"

        'Create instance of Word
        Set OpenWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        OpenWord.Visible = True

        'Open the document
        OpenWord.Documents.Open FileName:=LevelIConf

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

I have several Courses that I send out confirmation letters for and each letter is different based on the course.  I would like to be able to push a button on the form and have correct document come up based on the course number.

Any help is appreciated.  I am a self taught coder and still have lots to learn.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please note I provide generic solution that may need to be adapted depending on your actual requirements/setup.

**Option 1: Your approach (using Word's mail-merge)**

You need the following setup:

- Two related tables:

[image]
[image]
[image]

- Query that returns path to the Conf Letter based on Course ID:

[image]

- Function that calls the query from previous step:

  ```
  Function GetConfLetterPathByCourseID(CourseID As Integer) As String

      GetConfLetterPathByCourseID = ""

      Dim qdf As QueryDef
      Dim rs As Recordset

      Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("GetConfLetterPathByCourseId")
      qdf.Parameters("CourseID_par") = CourseID
      Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset

      If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
          GetConfLetterPathByCourseID = rs("ConfLetterPath")
      End If

  End Function
  ```
- Form with the Send button. Something like this:

[image]

- And, finally, the Sub for the Send Button:

  ```
  Sub ConfLetterButton_Click()

      DoCmd.SetWarnings False

      Dim LevelIConf As String
      Dim OpenWord As Object

      'Path to word document
      LevelIConf = GetConfLetterPathByCourseID(Me.CourseID)

      'Create instance of Word
      Set OpenWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      OpenWord.Visible = True

      'Open the document
      OpenWord.Documents.Open FileName:=LevelIConf

      DoCmd.SetWarnings True

  End Sub
  ```

**Please note**, I altered slightly your code (e.g. removed Index type, removed Docmd.OpenQuery)

**Option 2**: Compose email in VBA code and attach the Conf Letter doc file using the Query/Function from option 1. I think [this link from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167323%28v=office.11%29.aspx) can provide some details. I did implement similar solution in the past. Worked pretty well.